# Htaccess: HTTPS redirection on page + sub pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

Im trying to set a htaccess rule that redirects all pages that come under a specific url to https they currently default to http.

Im trying to set a overall rule that includes anything after the /enrolments/ page.

As multiple locations are included and more being added, so i do not wish to add a new rule for specific pages each time a new subpage is added.

MAIN: http://www.domain.com/enrolments/

SUB : http://www.domain.com/enrolments/uk

SUB :http://www.domain.com/enrolments/USA

Does anyone have a method of setting https on the enrolments page and any generated sub pages.

Cheers

Comment: Sure, this question has been answered alone here on StackOverflow about 453726472 times. I am sure you can find examples when you search a bit...

Comment: I have searched and tried many options, with no result, this is why i have asked.

Comment: Then you should add that information to your question, since it is important. Especially _why_ all those examples did not answer your question and what you tried so far and why that did not work. Without that this question looks like you did not even try yourself but want others to do your work for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# HTTPS page Redirects
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
RewriteRule ^/?enrolments/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/enrolments/$1 [R,L]
#END https redirects
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Hope this helps :)